# Login asp.net identity with OWIN middleware token endpoint without password?

Tags: asp.net-web-api, asp.net-identity, owin

I have asp.net web API application with asp.net identity with Owin Middleware token endpoint. Is it possible to login without password in this approach?

Comment: Please clarify **exactly** what you mean by "login without password". Because without a password, how will your users authenticate?